# Why does my laptop shut down on its own?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, troubleshooting, shutdown, acer-aspire

My laptop shuts down.

It happened several times so far, and there is a pattern; after I leave it for an hour or so, power saving activates, and then I start using it again for 10 - 15 minutes when it shuts down with no prior warning.

I'm pretty sure that it's not an overheating issue, because I keep it in a fairly cold room, and the laptop is not hot at all after shutting down (it can get much warmer, without shutting down).

I use Windows 7 so that could be the problem, because I never had this problem while using Windows XP. The laptop is an Acer Aspire.

Do you know if there are some settings in Win 7 that can be changed to stop this?

Comment: does it actually 'shut down' or does it cut off immediately?

Comment: Cuts off immediately.

Comment: Could this person who voted -1 please explain why?

Comment: People seem to be quite unforgiving about grammar/spelling errors; I would assume that would be the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it cuts off immediately, it is very likely to be an overheating or power problem.

By "power-saving activates" do you mean the fans spin down, etc?
If they fail to spin back up again it's perfectly feasible that the CPU will overheat, even in 10-15 minutes in a cold room.

Consider either opening up and cleaning laptop air intakes, or purchasing a can of compressed air to blow out dust.

Comment: I'm not sure about the fans, I only noticed that screen light becomes darker and then turns black completely (I haven't activated any screensavers).

Comment: i had a laptop that did this too.  cleaning it out helped a little, the first time.  didn't take long for it to stop helping.  to really fix the problem i had to clean off the old crusty thermal paste (from the CPU & heatsink) and apply some fresh.

Comment: I turned off all those power saving settings, laptop is plugged all the time anyway (battery is 1 year old - almost useless). 
I postponed the openning of the laptop, I was afraid that I could make things worse, or create another problem.
Anyway, this solved problem for now.

Comment: A overheating problem showing up after an hour of inactivity and 10 minutes use sounds strange...

Comment: Agreed, but I stand-by this 10 year old answer :). If the heat pipe is cracked, fan is dead, vents are clogged, or heat pipe is thermally-disconnected from CPU then very reasonable that overheat could occur in minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably not the battery but a badly implemented Acer design feature. On the reverse side, there are a series of Torx screws. If the hardware detects any are open, it kills power as a "safety" feature. This is done to reduce the risk of a fire should the user open the case and turn on power to the laptop. This sounds nice, but the feature has been implemented poorly because the screws are self-loosing over time! Try tightening the screws hard. A Torx screwdriver (with changeable heads) can be picked up from a good hardware store for a few dollars.

The problem (with resolution) is [described in great detail here](https://superuser.com/questions/1008809/laptop-shuts-down-suddenly-when-running-on-battery).

When you opened the case (to blow out dust) the problem was probably *actually* solved when you closed the case afterwards...! :o)